# Adding elements from an array to a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

As the title says, would it be possible to add elements from a string array to a struct array? For example, I have my following code:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 500

typedef struct User
{
    char fullName[MAX_SIZE];
    char description[MAX_SIZE];
    char userName[MAX_SIZE];
    char password[MAX_SIZE];
} userData[MAX_SIZE];

int main (void)
{
    int j=0;
    int numData=0;
    char* data[500];
    char line[500];
    int i=0;
    userData newUser;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("users.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        data[i]=strdup(line);
        i++;
        numData++;
    }
    for (j=0 ; j<numData+1; j++) {
        printf("%s", data[j]);
    }

    fclose(file); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Right now what this code does is to add the lines from my users.txt file to a string array. What I'd like to do now is to add the elements from this string array to my struct array, for example like this:

newUser[1].fullName = first element of the string array

newUser[1].description = second element of the string array

...

etc

Would this be possible? Or is there a way of adding the the lines from the file to my struct array in the format I explained above without using the string array?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I know I'm not the only one curious as to where `programs` comes from. And I'm pretty sure `#include<stdlib.>` is going to puke as well. Please, *please*, post *real* code.

Comment: No you are not @WhozCraig. I am curious too and for why you had to indent his code, it wouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I think programs is just supposed to be data instead.

Comment: Am I missing something here (or going blind), where is `programs[]` declared, and where is `data` filled. Right now it looks like a horrible train wreck of both reading and writing to undeclared/uninitialized areas of memory. Have you event tried to compile this code? This new header `stdlib.` is nowhere to be found, and presuming your meant `stdlib.h`, the compile errors on `programs undeclared`...

Comment: sorry for the variable names, I was changing them between my files and somehow it got unchanged, it should be fine now. My code is indented in my original files but somehow whenever I copy it to as SO question I can't manage to do it (sorry again).

Answer (score 0):

After reading the line you can use sscanf function to fill the i'th element of your structure array. You don't need to use string array more. You can specify your string format in sscanf and fill all fields of i'th new user in loop.